# Discord Audit Log

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
   if (oldMember.nickname !==
     newMember.nickname) {
   send_log(
     c,
     member.guild,
     "Orange",
     "Nickname Update",
     `${member.user.tag}'s nickname was ${oldNickname} and is now ${newMember.nickname}`);
   }
   });
```

Trying to make a nickname change discord bot using **Javascript**. Seeing if anyone can help me

Error

```
      if (oldMember.nickname !==
                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'nickname' of undefined
```

When I've removed the `if` statement and change all the others to...
`` ${member.user.tag}'s nickname was ${oldNickname} and is now ${newNickname}`); ``

It presents another issue which is that "newNickname" is undefined.

Comment: Is this in a guildMemberUpdate event?

Comment: You don't seem to have defined `oldMember`. Did you mean to use `oldNickname`?

Comment: We cant help you unless you'll show us how do you define tho `oldMember` constant/variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that may work for what you want to do

```js
client.on('guildMemberUpdate', async (oldM, newM) => {
    let oldNick = oldM.nickname;
    let newNick = newM.nickname;
    if (newNick !== oldNick) {
        send_log(
            c,
            newM.guild,
            "Orange",
            "Nickname Update",
            `${newM.user.tag}'s nickname was ${oldNick} and is now ${newNick}`
        );
        // I'm not sure what your send_log function is, I'm assuming it's correct. oldNick is the old nickname and newNick is the new one 
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey, just to let you know.

`(node:7768) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: member is not defined` it's throwing errors back

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change a few variables. It should be working now

Comment: Tried the code. No errors, but nothing is being posted on the logging channel.

Comment: Do you have guildMembers intent enabled from discord developer portal?

Comment: Indeed, all my other logging's work. Like "Message Delete" but nicknames just won't work xD

Comment: `async function send_log(c, guild, color, title, description, thumb) {
  try {
    //CREATE THE EMBED
    const LogEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor(color ? color : "BLACK")
      .setDescription(description ? description.substr(0, 2048) : "\u200b")
      .setTitle(title ? title.substr(0, 256) : "\u200b")
      .setTimestamp()
      .setThumbnail(thumb ? thumb : guild.iconURL({ format: "png" }))
      .setFooter(
        guild.name + " | powered by: milrato.eu & Modified by ShinchanOP",
        guild.iconURL({ format: "png" })
      );`

Got it to work btw.

Comment: Ok, if it worked please checkmark (✔️) my answer.